# Quadratic variation of an integral with respect to a random measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

It is well-known that if $F(s,\omega)$ is a "nice" measurable function and $W$ is a Brownian motion, then
$$
M_t:=\int_0^t F(s,\omega) dW_s
$$ 
is a continuous square integrable martingale and its quadratic variation is 
$$
[M]_t=\int_0^t F^2(s,\omega) ds.
$$

Now let us consider an integral with respect to a compensated Poisson measure $\widetilde N(ds,dx)$. Put
$$
R_t:=\int_0^t\int_\mathbb{|r|\le1} G(x,s,\omega) \widetilde N(ds,dx),
$$
where $G$ is again some "nice" function. It is known that $R$ is a cadlag (but not continuous!) martingale. What is the formula for its quadratic variation?

Comment: $[R]_t=\int_0^t\int_{|x|\le1}G^2(x,s,\omega)\,N(ds,dx)$, $\langle R \rangle_t =\int_0^t\int_{|x|\le1}G^2(x,s,\omega)\,ds L(dx)$.

Comment: @JGWang Thanks a lot! This was exactly what I was looking for.